# Android Studio won't identify Gradle's Version Catalog nested dependency

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I've heard recently about [Gradle's Version Catalog](https://melix.github.io/blog/2021/03/version-catalogs.html) and decided to give it a try... Everything setup, Gradle wrapper set to `gradle-7.0-rc-2` and everything runs fine and I am able to build.

Android Studio, however won't identify nested dependencies, showing this exception:

> Cannot access class 'org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.AndroidxLibraryAccessors'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

app/build.gradle.kts

```
implementation(libs.androidx.coreKtx)
```

gradle/libs.versions.toml

```
androidx_coreKtx = "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-beta03"
```

How may I get rid of that AS error?

Comment: This appears to be an IDE issue, but it was erroneously closed down as obsolete: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-1221

Answer (score 1):

It looks like issue was fixed by IntellIJ team (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-1221) a while ago, but stable Android Studio uses fairly old IntelliJ platform.

On the bright side, it appears to be fixed in the new Android Studio Canary (`Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 15` works fine).

I've created an issue on Google's bugtracker. I know the chance is slim, but maybe they notice it and backport the fix to 4.2:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187326581

Comment: By the time of writing I was using the Canary 13. I'll try updating to 15 asap to see if it works

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to rename `androidx_coreKtx` to `androidx-coreKtx`? After that change you should be able to use `implementation(libs.androidx.coreKtx)`

Make sure that you have `enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")` in your `settings.gradle(.kts)`

Comment: Build works, so it is not anything in gradle files. This is IDE issue.